# Dynamically grow menu based on terms in vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes

As terms are added to a vocabulary, I need these terms to be incorporated into a menu with a custom URL structure.  For example, I might have the `Restaurant Taxonomy` which has the following terms:

- McDonalds
- Taco Bell
- Wendys

I need to have a menu generated that matches a particular pattern with the term names plugged in - this pattern can be arbitrary.  For example, I have the pattern `/restaurants/<term-name>` would generate a menu with the following links:

- /restaurants/mcdonalds
- /restaurants/taco-bell
- /restaurants/wendys

As terms are added, this menu needs to grow dynamically.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module will be able to handle that...

> Transform any of your taxonomy vocabularies into existing menus easily!
>
> Features
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

The module page also links to a tutorial called [How to add a block menu of tags (or other taxonomy terms) on a Drupal site](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-add-block-menu-tags-or-other-taxonomy-terms-drupal-site) in conjunction with the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module in case you need that functionality.